# How do I rewrite this HTML to validate to XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

How do I rewrite this HTML to validate to XHTML 1.0 Strict?

```
<div>
    <a href="link.html">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</div>
```

My intent is to have the entire div serve as a clickable link. The content within simply describes the contents of the destination page. W3 Validator says I can't have a block element (`<p>`) inside a span tag (`<a>`).

How do I rearrange this so that my DIVs remain block links?

Comment: Is it possible to set display: block in CSS for the a tag?  Would that work?

Comment: The `a` tag is already set to display block, which is why it works as I want it to. It doesn't validate though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not allowed to wrap a block level element in an inline level element so you have a few alternatives.

- You can wrap every line that you want linked in the `<a href="link.html">...</a>`

  ```
  <div>
      <p><a href="link.html">Some text</a></p>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="link.html">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="link.html">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="link.html">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>​
  ```
- You can add a javascript `onclick` function to reproduce the same results.

  ```
   //jQuery
   ​$('div').click(function() {
       window.location = 'link.html';
   });​​​​​​

   //Non jQuery
   document.getElementById('yourDiv').onclick = function() {
       window.location = 'link.html';
   }
  ```

  - If you use the Javascript, make sure you use CSS to make it apparent that the contents are links. I'd recommend pseudo classes

    ```
    div {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #0000FF;//or whatever your link color is
    }
    div li:hover, p:hover {
        color: #CC00FF;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    ```

    ​

Comment: You should mention that this solution depends on jQuery.

Comment: Hi Robert! If I use the jQuery function, where do I put it? The page in question has anywhere from 5 to 30 of these div blocks, each going to a different page.

Comment: I'd wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function() {...here...});` Be sure to change the `div` selector to something relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rearrange it to make the block a link. What you could do is to make every single element in the block a link, or you can use javascript.

```
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='link.html'">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: I'd usually discourage the use of `onclick` as an attribute, but I approve of your use of `cursor:pointer` which has been neglected in the other posts. +1

Comment: @LeguRi, I agree with you, normally I don't use it too, but I wanted to present a quick and short solution. And Robert already presented the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

As is, your fragment is valid HTML5.  Use that instead and your problem vanishes.  All you have to do is change the doctype to `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: Really!? Do you have any links to cite? Did they ditch the whole "block-level versus inline level" thing in HTML5?

Comment: Yup.  See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/content-models.html -- particularly the description of "flow content", which seems to have subsumed both categories; also, at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element the `<a>` element is specifically allowed to contain "any flow content" but to still be treated as "phrasing content" if its contents are entirely "phrasing content".

Comment: Also, http://validator.nu/ is an HTML5 validator.  I determined my original answer by pasting the OP's fragment into the skeleton document it gives you.  No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your <UL> is also a block element, so it won't work there either.  How about:

```
<div onclick="location.href = 'link.html'">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```